# How to determine system value for _POSIX_PATH_MAX

Tags: c, unix, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-mint

Can anyone please tell me how to find the system value for `_POSIX_PATH_MAX` in Linux mint? I know that it is available in the <limits.h> file but I do not know how to find its value.

Comment: its value is the value of the symbol, you normally don't have to know the value. Write your code with this symbol and never make any assumption about its real value. This is the way you will have portable code.

Answer (score 3):

The tool to use, according to POSIX, is named [getconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html)(1):

```
  $ getconf _POSIX_PATH_MAX
  256
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way to get it's value.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "unistd.h"
#include "limits.h"

int main()
{
    printf ("Value :: %d \n", _POSIX_PATH_MAX);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: System includes should be address via `#include <file.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

`#define` one of the following

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 1 /* or any value larger then 1 */
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

before `#include`ing `<limits.h>`and the compiler will see `_POSIX_PATH_MAX`.

You also can specify this on the command line via the compiler option `-D`:

```
gcc -c main.c -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=1
```

for example.